# Realm with fully offline work (never online)

Tags: mongodb, react-native, realm

I'm trying to understand how every element of mongoDB works  but I'm really confused about how the offline is handled.

Going to: https://realm.io/

I read this:

> Realm’s mobile database is an open source, developer-friendly alternative to CoreData and SQLite. Start in minutes, port your app in hours, and save yourself weeks of work.

And then this part where it mentions the offline part:

> Designed for Offline Use

Does this means that Realm can be used as a completely offline database in a mobile app?

if i understand correctly, this database would work similarly to Android Room where I store data using Objects/Documents.

Because when I go to the "Let's start" section, I'm being redirected to here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/get-started/introduction-mobile/

Where I read this part:

> Before you begin, you will need a MongoDB Atlas account. You can learn more about creating an Atlas account in the Atlas Getting Started documentation

**So my first question:** why I need an Atlas account? I understand that the Atlas is to have a MongoDB database in the cloud. Why I need this if I want to work with a offline database?

I guess that the tutorial want to show all the tools working together. So maybe that step can be skipped. But then going to the React Native Tutorial, I see this part:

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/react-native/#std-label-react-native-tutorial

> Connect to Your MongoDB Realm App

> **To get the app working with your backend**, you first need to instantiate the Realm app. The Realm app is the interface to the MongoDB Realm backend. Navigate to the getRealmApp.js file and complete the getRealmApp()

This part of code seems really important:

```
// Returns the shared instance of the Realm app.
export function getRealmApp() {
  if (app === undefined) {
    const appId = "<your Realm app ID here>"; // Set Realm app ID here.
    const appConfig = {
      id: appId,
      timeout: 10000,
      app: {
        name: "default",
        version: "0",
      },
    };
    app = new Realm.App(appConfig);
  }
  return app;
}
```

the code is forcing me to indicate the AppId that I get in the Realm Console.

**So my second question:** How can make this part offline? Should I just skip the appId? Would this work?

Is this possible or Realm Is not really suited for completely offline work?

Answer (score 10):

```
I'm really confused about how the offline is handled.
```

Realm is an offline first database and all data is stored locally in a file and then sync's to the server later if you're using MongoDB Realm Sync

> Does this means that Realm can be used as a completely offline
> database in a mobile app?

For sure. Data is stored in a file as mentioned.

> So my first question: why I need an Atlas account?

You don't need an Atlas account for offline use. You would need to set up an account to be able to access the MongoDB Realm Console and configure a Realm App for Sync'ing

> This part of code seems really important:

The code in your question is used when you're using MongoDB Realm Sync. It's not needed for offline only use.

> So my second question: How can make this part offline? Should I just
> skip the appId? Would this work?

You don't need that code for offline only use.

> Is this possible or Realm Is not really suited for completely offline
> work?

It is well suited for offline only work and if you want to transition to an online model, it's well suited for that too.

If you want to use Realm offline only see the documentation [Open a Local (Non-Synced) Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/react-native/open-a-realm/#open-a-local--non-synced--realm) which shows

> To open a local (non-synced) realm, pass a Configuration() object to
> either Realm.open() or new Realm(). The following example creates a
> Configuration object with a path property that defines the local file
> path to store data.

```
const config = {
   schema: [schemas.TaskSchema, schemas.UserSchema, schemas.ProjectSchema],
   path: "./myrealm/data"
};
const realm = await Realm.open(config);
```

once you have the realm var, you can then work with realm locally:

```
// Query realm for all instances of the "Task" type.
const tasks = realm.objects("Task");
```

Comment: So it is possible to have Realm Sync without Altlas? (Synchronize 2 databases without access to internet)

Comment: @NicolasVERHELST No. Realm is an offline first database so it would exist on a single device. If you want to share data, you would need to leverage Sync which allows multiple devices to access the same data.

Comment: does anyone have code for the offline version of the get started tutorial?

Comment: @FrankFu The local-only code would use `const realm = await Realm.open` any time you wanted to access the local realm. The code for the offline version is at the link in my answer [Open & Close a Local Realm - React Native SDK](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/open-and-close-a-local-realm/#open-a-local--non-synced--realm)

Comment: @Jay thanks. I don't think the rest of the tutorial works even with that change though. I think the tutorial over promotes their cloud services.

Comment: @FrankFu Keep in mind that when local only you need to replace any calls for a Realm that would normally sync to the server with the local only calls and remove all of the Auth and Team references as that's not needed. Realm is marketed and is a offline-first database so it would 'have to' work offline (local) as well as online. (you have a good point there should be a pure offline version of the tutorial as well, so perhaps contacting them directly with your request would be in order. OR head over the Realm forums and make a post; SO is not the right forum for that)

Comment: @Jay Agreed. I'll make a post on the Realm forums when I'm stuck next but I've managed to Google my way out of it for now.

Comment: Hi guys, i'm trying to setup local offline db, do you have made any special post/tutorial for offline use? 
Thanks

Comment: @AdnanBoota The [Quick Start](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/quick-start/) has some really good information but the best resource is the [Tutorial: Part 1](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/ios-swift/) which shows how to set up an *offline* To Do list, which you can then later take online with the rest of the tutorial.