# Offline Atlas cluster to use Realm Sync without internet?

Tags: database, mongodb, synchronization, realm

### My understanding of Realm Sync

I understood it is possible to use [Realm Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/) on a (sometimes) [offline](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/#offline-first) application/client.
This Realm Sync would manage the connection to [the database](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/get-started/glossary/#std-term-linked-cluster) along with [conflict resolution](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/#conflict-resolution).
But, as I understood, Realm Sync would need to connect to an *Atlas Cluster* (a server).

I also understood [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66462572/11248859) that offline is totally ok if Realm Sync is not used.

### The question

Is it possible to have an **offline** instance of that *Atlas Cluster* (i.e. not in the cloud)?

### Why this question?

I need to build some database synchronisation for a project that will NEVER have access to internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know, wether it is possible to write data offline on a mobile device and the sync will happen later, once the device is online again, am I right?

Realm Sync is a possible way to use then, yes.
Once the database was initialized once on the mobile (starting the app first for example), you can read and write everything offline. If there is a connection available, everything will get synced to the MongoDB Atlas Cluster. The whole conflict-resulution will happen in the cloud and you don't need to worry about it again.

Comment: What I was looking for was the possibility to never use the cloud: replace MongoDB Atlas Cluster by some sort of offline instance. As you tell me that the conflict resolution will happen in the cloud, I understand that I would need the cloud, but the solution I am developing will NEVER have access to internet. So MongoDB is not compatible with my project. (The project will be in a separate network with no access to internet).

Comment: Ok I understand. I was a bit confused with the sync but no internet solution. I'm actually not sure if you can use mongoDB on a private server system, I'd just ask in their community, they always help super fast :) 
Here's a link: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/

Comment: I asked on their community and got [an answer](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/offline-atlas-cluster-to-use-realm-sync-without-internet/116195/2?u=nicolas_verhelst).